# jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Im am struggling with trying to figure out a selector for this kind of html

```
<input type="hidden" value="2.0" name="A_ITEM-AMOUNT[1]">
```

Im trying to filter alot of these lines with a jQuery expression but has no luck in my matches ( either too much or no match at all).

I'm using the following jquery string.

```
 $("[id$='aform']").contents()
   .filter("[name^='A_ITEM-AMOUNT\\[1']")
   .each(function (index,element)
```

Any ideas?

Best Regards Olme

Comment: `filter("[name^='A_ITEM-AMOUNT\[1']")`? How can you have `BACKSLASH`? And your `'` is in front of `]`, should it be there?

Comment: I thougt you had to escape [] with \\ ? AS for the ' I dont really know to be honest. Found this in the api documentation "If you wish to use any of the meta-characters (#;&,.+*~':"!^$[]()=>|/ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\. For example, if you have an an input with name="names[]", you can use the selector $("input[name=names\\[\\]]")."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simpler selector, like this:

```
$("[id$='aform'] input[name='A_ITEM-AMOUNT[1]']").each(function(index, element) {
  //do something
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6HqVP/), also if the `[id$='aform']` refers to a `<form>`, make it `form[id$='aform']` to be *much* more efficient.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why would that version be more efficient?

Comment: @Buzzzz - Without an element selector, it's checking *every* element in the DOM unnecessarily for the attribute, with `form` it'll do a `document.getElementsByTagName()` first, greatly narrowing the search.  Also don't forget to accept answers on this and other questions if they resolve your issue, via the check on the left :)